# Intent of [basic.execution] p5 sentence 2

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, full-expression

[[basic.execution] p5 sentence 2](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.exec#intro.execution-5.sentence-2) states:

> If a language construct is defined to produce an implicit call of a function, a use of the language construct is considered to be an expression for the purposes of this definition.

However, the intent of this sentence is not immediately clear. My best guess is that it is here in order to ensure proper sequencing and to make sure that temporaries are not destroyed before any implicit function calls complete, however, I cannot see a situation where this would apply and change the meaning of some code. For example:

```
struct S { };
const S& f() { return {}; }
```

Here, the `return` statement would be considered an expression, and the operand `{}` would also be considered an expression, and therefore a subexpression of the `return` statement. Is this the intent of the sentence? Where else would this apply and have a meaningful effect?

Comment: This sentence appears since some very old version of the standard. In that version, there is a note saying this sentence applies for initializers, which is deleted by [issue 392](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#392), and is covered by [\[intro.execution\]/5.4](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.exec#intro.execution-5.4) in the current version. I don't know if this sentence applies for the `return` statement, since there is already [a rule](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.return#3) handling such cases.

Comment: By the way, there is no constructor called in your example, so this sentence does not apply anyway. You may consider using `struct S {S() {}};` instead.

Comment: In C++98 it was simply (§1.9.12) "*A full-expression is an expression that is not a subexpression of another expression. If a language construct is defined to produce an implicit call of a function, a use of the language construct is considered to be an expression for the purposes of this definition.*". It basically means anything that calls anything gets life-extended to the outermost *full-expression*.

Comment: @xskxzr What you linked about return statements only defines the sequencing for the destruction of temporaries and variables. Also, good catch on it being an aggregate. I've figured it out since I posted this question.

Answer (score 2):

The key phrase is "in the context of this definition", i.e. the definition of *full-expression*.

It's just saying that the rules of a *full-expression* (e.g. temporary lifetime) will also apply for the entirety of your `return` statement, even though it's not otherwise enumerated in the list of things that constitute a *full-expression*.

And that's because it involves an implicit function call (a ctor call); if it didn't, then the point would be moot.

It doesn't "change the meaning" of any code.

Comment: It does change the meaning, since if the functiona that the return statement invokes weren't part of the full-expression, then they would be destroyed before the functions were called.

Comment: Well, only in the sense that literally any rule of the standard "changes the meaning" from if said rule didn't exist. But there's no weirdness or ambiguity here, it's just part of the definition of a _full-expression_.

Comment: There's probably also something interesting related to the subexpression rule that makes this worthy of defining in such a manner but meh - someone more interested in lawyering will have to produce a better answer to cover that :P

Comment: As for the intent, is what I wrote in my question correct?

Comment: I'm curious what practical problem you're trying to solve here

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out the intent of that sentence mostly

Comment: Yes I got that but _why_?

Comment: I just like to understand the standard

Comment: Anyways, is my interpretation of the intent correct?